# Separating values for UI from View

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

I'd like to create a NSObject subclass which would hold all my values for UIView.

Problem - what's the right way to do that?

1. Using "extern" and class method combination?
2. Using "extern" and #define combination?
3. Using only #define on class methods?

UI elements(e.g. UIColor) can't be initialized using "extern *const" method.

Writing a class methods for each value seems like too much.

Macros are plain(no coloring, etc.) and are declared only in header file.

Isn't there are better solution, which would hold all my ints,floats, colors in same place. And which is not a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not macros?

For UIColor you can use:

```
#define RGBA_COLOR(r, g, b, a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r/255.0) green:(g/255.0) blue:(b/255.0) alpha:a]

#define MY_GREEN_COLOR RGBA_COLOR(60, 192, 174, 1.0)
```

And then you can use MY_GREEN_COLOR without problems:

```
UIColor *color = MY_GREEN_COLOR;
```

And the same for int, floats and so on:

```
#define MY_INT 83
```

I usually have a "Globals.h" file with all this stuff.

Comment: I just like to keep all things in same file. Using macros I will have UIColors in my .h file, constants in my .m But thanks, I will mark your answer as correct, even though I went with class methods.